# What is an elegant way of finding matches between properties of two arrays of structures?

Tags: swift

I've seen various answers online about finding matches between two arrays including the use of intersect and filter, but these solutions don't seem possible when dealing with structures and their properties.

```
struct Example {var name: String}

var arr1 = [Example(name: "Sam"), Example(name: "Ash"), Example(name: "Mike")]
var arr2 = [Example(name: "David"), Example(name: "Sam"), Example(name: "Leonard")]
```

Without using a bunch of "for loops", I want to remove Sam from arr1 if it has a match in arr2. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You cannot do this even if you use "a bunch of for loops". `arr1` is a `let` constant. Do you want to make a new array without Sam, or is `arr1` meant to be a `var` instead?

Comment: Oh sorry. yes, both arrays are meant to be vars. ill edit

Comment: @LionelYu `arr2` can still be `let` since you only need to modify `arr1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first put all the names in `arr2` in a set, and then use [`removeAll`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/removeall(where:)-6bd6r) to remove from `arr1`. In `removeAll`, you can specify a condition, and this is where you query the set to see if the `Example` in `arr1` has a name that matches one of those in `arr2`.

```
let namesToExclude = Set(arr2.map(\.name))
arr1.removeAll { namesToExclude.contains($0.name) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Great, really beautiful solution, and I never knew about the removeAll function so extra bonus points for teaching me something new today.